# "Проверен нашим главным бухгалтером, Ивановой Л.П" Здесь уточнение или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Вот, предложение:

> Этот отчет уже проверен нашим главным бухгалтером, Ивановой Л.П.

ИЛИ

> Этот отчет уже проверен нашим главным бухгалтером Ивановой Л.П.

Надо ли ставить запятую в этом предложении? Я поставила, ибо считаю, что это уточнение, но может  оба варианта верны?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь приложение стоит перед определяемым словом и характеризует его, поэтому запятая не ставится. Пример: Великий русский поэт А.С.Пушкин родился в Москве. Если бы было наоборот - запятая требовалась бы. Отчет проверен Ивановой, нашим главным бухгалтером (или лучше: Отчет проверен Ивановой - нашим главным бухгалтером)

Answer (score 0):

ПРАВИЛО

Теоретически возможны три варианта постановки знаков препинания в подобных случаях, например:

1) Приехала сестра Маша (необособленный вариант НАР+СОБСТВ, приложение перед определяемым словом).

2) Приехала сестра, Маша(НАР+СОБСТВ, уточнение).

3) Приехала Маша, сестра (СОБСТВ+НАР, уточнение).

РЕШЕНИЕ

1) Базовый вариант с полной информацией: "Этот отчет уже проверен нашим главным бухгалтером Ивановой Л.П."

2) Вариант с обособлением используется в том случае, если важна только должность проверяющего: "Этот отчет уже проверен нашим главным бухгалтером, Ивановой Л.П."